# Generate Google maps from URL

Tags: jquery, google-maps

Is there a way to plot multiple addresses on a single static map from within the Google Maps API?

Here is an example of a single address plotted:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=H9R1H3+57%20EASTVIEW%20AVENUE
```

What would an example URL of this look like?

Answer (score 3):

There is a jquery plugin , i have used it and it works great

**check**

http://gmap.nurtext.de/examples.html

Comment: unfortunately I am deploying for handheld devices including old Blackberries, which is not very very javascript friendly.

Answer (score 2):

[Google Maps API](http://mapki.com/wiki/Google_Map_Parameters)

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to create a KML file that outputs mulitple points.

It could even be a dynamic script.

eg

http://server.com/kml?a=adress+one&b=address+two&c=address+three

could be a dynamic script that reads the address from the URL, and outputs KML code.

Can then pass this url to Maps (maps accepts the URL of a KML file in the q= param - propelly encoded of course)

Comment: Demo http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?q=http:%2F%2Fnearby.org.uk%2Fa2k.php%3Fa%3DBirmingham,%2BUK%26b%3Dlondon,uk%26c%3Dbrighton,uk

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use a KML file, we can directly access Google Places API. Google Places API response consists of all (Actually max. 20) places around the current location.
an example of the url request is as shown below.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyAiFpFd85eMtfbvmVNEYuNds5TEF9FjIPI
```

Response may be in Json or XML, depends on the response we are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this?

[http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY&zoom=13&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap
&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C40.702147,-74.015794&markers=color:green%7Clabel:G%7C40.711614,-74.012318
&markers=color:red%7Ccolor:red%7Clabel:C%7C40.718217,-73.998284&sensor=false](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn%20Bridge,New%20York,NY&zoom=13&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap%20&markers=color%3ablue%7Clabel%3aS%7C40.702147,-74.015794&markers=color%3agreen%7Clabel%3aG%7C40.711614,-74.012318%20&markers=color%3ared%7Ccolor%3ared%7Clabel%3aC%7C40.718217,-73.998284&sensor=false)

Have a look at the static maps api.  For reference, the static maps api is different from the regular google maps api.  So, the google maps api (current is v3) is a different api from the static maps api (current is v2).

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/